# Regex for 3 types of address

Tags: c#, regex

I have 3 different patterns of address:

```
Avenue T, 55 - Sumiton, AL - USA
Avenue T - Sumiton, AL - USA
Sumiton, AL - USA
```

which means: `[address][,][number][-][county][,][state][-][country]`

I'm trying to use this regex but not working correctly:

```
(?<street>.*\,)(?:\s*(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*))?\s*(?<county>.*\,)?\s*(?<State>.*\-)?\s*(?<Country>.*)
```

[Regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(?%3Cstreet%3E.*%5C,)(?:%5Cs*(?%3Cnumber%3E[1-9][0-9]*))?%5Cs*(?%3Ccounty%3E.*%5C,)?%5Cs*(?%3CState%3E.*%5C-)?%5Cs*(?%3CCountry%3E.*)&i=Test%20Avenue%20T,%2055%20-%20Sumiton,%20AL%20-%20USA%0ATest%20Avenue%20T%20-%20Sumiton,%20AL%20-%20USA%0ATest%20Sumiton,%20AL%20-%20USA)

any help please? ty

Comment: Yeah, parsing addresses is difficult. Could you point out the `[address][,][number][-][county][,][state][-][country]` per line?

Comment: Try `^(?<street>[^,]*),(?:\s*(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*))?(?:\s*-\s*(?<county>[^,]*),)?(?:\s*(?<State>.*)-)?\s*(?<Country>.*)$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it gave me 0 matches

Comment: Ok, you did not test it in the real environement

Comment: I would avoid regex at all. Code is extremelly difficult to maintain and modify. Create some AddressParser class and unittest it as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your three patterns can be described like

```
${street}, ${number} - ${county}, ${State} - ${Country}
OPTIONAL   OPTIONAL   OBLIGATORY  OBLIGATORY OBLIGATORY
```

You may use

```
^(?!$)(?<street>.*?(?=(?:,\s*\d+)?\s*-\s*\w+,))?(?:,\s*(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*))?\s*(?:-\s*)?(?<county>[\w\s]+),\s*(?<State>[A-Z]{2})\s*-\s*(?<Country>.*)$
```

If you need to extract them from the a multiline string use

```
(?m)^(?!\r?$)(?<street>.*?(?=(?:,\s*\d+)?\s*-\s*\w+,))?(?:,\s*(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*))?\s*(?:-\s*)?(?<county>[\w\s]+),\s*(?<State>[A-Z]{2})\s*-\s*(?<Country>.*)\r?$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F!%5Cr%3F%24%29%28%3F%3Cstreet%3E.*%3F%28%3F%3D%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cs*%5Cd%2B%29%3F%5Cs*-%5Cs*%5Cw%2B%2C%29%29%3F%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cs*%28%3F%3Cnumber%3E%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D*%29%29%3F%5Cs*%28%3F%3A-%5Cs*%29%3F%28%3F%3Ccounty%3E%5B%5Cw%5Cs%5D%2B%29%2C%5Cs*%28%3F%3CState%3E%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D%29%5Cs*-%5Cs*%28%3F%3CCountry%3E.*%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=Avenue%20T%2C%2055%20-%20Sumiton%2C%20AL%20-%20USA%0D%0AAvenue%20T%20-%20Sumiton%2C%20AL%20-%20USA%0D%0ASumiton%2C%20AL%20-%20USA%0D%0A&o=xm). Results:

[image]

So, the street group is only populated if there is an optional number group with an obligtory county group following.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string/line (if `(?m)` is used)
- `(?!$)` / `(?!\r?$)` - a negative lookahead preventing an empty string / line match
- `(?<street>.*?(?=(?:,\s*\d+)?\s*-\s*\w+,))?` - Group "street": any 0+ chars as few as possible up to an optional sequence of `,`, 0+ whitespaces, 1+ digits and then a `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces, 1+ word chars and a `,`
- `(?:,\s*(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching `,`, 0+ whitespaces and then captures into Group "number" a digit from `1` to `9` and then any 0+ digits
- `\s*(?:-\s*)?(?<county>[\w\s]+)` - 0+ whitespaces, an optional sequence of a hyphen and then 0+ whitespaces, then captures into Group "county" any 1+ word and whitespace chars
- `,\s*(?<State>[A-Z]{2})`  - a comma,  0+ whitespaces and then captures into Group "State" 2 uppercase letters
- `\s*-\s*` - a  hyphen enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<Country>.*)` - Group "country": any 0+ chars other than LF as many as possible
- `$` - start of string/line.

Comment: it helped me a lot, just one problem: the line 2 Sumiton is the county not the street

Comment: @aasp It is there in the county column.

Comment: @aasp I updated the pattern to avoid matching an empty string/line. `\r?` is there because .NET regex matches `$` only before LF, not CRLF.

Comment: line 2 I mean index 2, it still shows Sumiton in Street column.

Comment: I  will check as soon as I can

Comment: I appreciate your attention and patience, i will try too

Comment: just out of curiosity, if I want include spaces in county, state and country? regex are really hard to understand....ty

Comment: @aasp Just add them: `^(?!$)(?<street>.*?(?=(?:,\s*\d+)?\s*-\s*[\w\s-]+,))?(?:,\s*(?<number>[1-9][0-9]*))?\s*(?:-\s*)?(?<county>[\w\s-]+),\s*(?<State>[A-Z-]{2})\s*-\s*(?<Country>.*)$`